# Аналог Color Highlighter для Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublime-text-3

В связи с тем, что плагин Color Highlighter больше не работает в scss/sass файлах, хотел узнать есть ли хорошие аналоги для ST3?

Comment: Gutter Color не предлагать :)

Comment: Это косяк 3-го Sublime, в большинстве редакторов это не проблема. Попробуйте временно Visual Studio Code, пока Sublime не разгребут эту кашу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел хорошую замену в "лице" ColorHelper